# How to generate "GCW" meta tag for Google Web Designer HTML5 ads?

Tags: google-web-designer

I've got a script that is generating my Google Web Designer template populated with content. I have two files being created, one is the editable template as I would normally edit in GWD, the other is a populated copy of the index.html extracted from a Published ad.

My problem is that I can edit and publish the Editable version to a new zip file and that uploads successfully to Google Ads, but the "pre-published" version that I am generating and zipping causes an error when I upload to Google Ads.

I have isolated the problem to this meta tag:
`<meta name="GCD" content="********"/>`

When I copy the GCD tag from my manually published index.html file to the auto-generated one (and then re-zip) it uploads fine. That is the only line that changes between the two zip files.

Does anyone know how GWD generates the GCD meta tag? If I could figure this out it would save me a ton of time opening and manually publishing the Ad package each time so would love to hear any ideas!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this looking for an answer, I didn't find an answer to the original issue, unfortunately, so I ended up making a JitBit macro that opens each file in GWD and exports it...
The downside is that JitBit has no variables so you have to create the list of your files manually or with a second script.

Here's the code, just need to save it as a `.mcr` file and have the macro program installed and it should run:
*(Naturally you need to replace the PATH TO FILE parts with your own template filenames etc..)*

```
OPEN FILE : C:\Program Files\Google\Google Web Designer\webdesigner.exe :  : 0
WAIT FOR : Google Web Designer : appear : 0 : 0
DELAY : 15000
REPEAT : 3 : 0 : 0 : Enter the number of iterations: : 0 : 0
SWITCH TO WINDOW : Google Web Designer : 0
DELAY : 500
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
Keyboard : O : KeyPress
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyUp
DELAY : 300
IF ITERATION EQUALS : 1 : 0
TYPE TEXT : C:\{***PATH TO FILE 1***}.html
ELSE
IF ITERATION EQUALS : 2 : 0
TYPE TEXT : C:\{***PATH TO FILE 2***}.html
ELSE
IF ITERATION EQUALS : 3 : 0
TYPE TEXT : C:\{***PATH TO FILE 3***}.html
ENDIF
ENDIF
ENDIF
DELAY : 300
Keyboard : Enter : KeyPress
DELAY : 3000
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
Keyboard : ShiftLeft : KeyDown
Keyboard : P : KeyPress
Keyboard : ShiftLeft : KeyUp
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyUp
DELAY : 500
Keyboard : Enter : KeyPress
DELAY : 500
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
DELAY : 500
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
Keyboard : A : KeyPress
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyUp
DELAY : 500
IF ITERATION EQUALS : 1 : 0
TYPE TEXT : {***ENTER NAME OF FILE 1***}
ELSE
IF ITERATION EQUALS : 2 : 0
TYPE TEXT : {***ENTER NAME OF FILE 2***}
ELSE
IF ITERATION EQUALS : 3 : 0
TYPE TEXT : {***ENTER NAME OF FILE 3***}
ENDIF
ENDIF
ENDIF
DELAY : 500
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
DELAY : 100
Keyboard : Enter : KeyPress
DELAY : 1000
ENDREPEAT
```